# Is there any way to find out which apt key belongs to which package?

Tags: apt, software-sources, debian

I have two public signing keys from the same developer in `apt-key list`. How to find out which is the key of the installed package?

Comment: Do you mean which key was used to sign that package or which key was added by that package? The former might not possible if you don't the package in your cache (a re-downloaded package might use a key). The latter might not be possible if they didn't use a file to store their own key and instead added it to `apt`'s truststore directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A package as such has no key. It are the software sources, including PPA's, that are signed.

You can determine from which repository a package was installed with the command:

```
apt-cache policy <package>
```

In turn, the command `apt-key list` can return the key of the PPA from which the package was installed.